# input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql

Tags: postgresql, backup, pg-restore

I take backup using

```
pg_dump db_production > postgres_db.dump
```

and then I copy it to localhost using scp.

Now when I import on my local db it gives an error

```
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

by using commad line

```
pg_restore -d db_development postgres_db.dump
```

Answer (score 202):

From the [`pg_dump`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) documentation:

Examples

**To dump a database called mydb into a SQL-script file**:

```
$ pg_dump mydb > db.sql
```

**To reload such a script into a (freshly created) database named newdb**:

```
$ psql -d newdb -f db.sql
```

To dump a database into a custom-format archive file:

```
$ pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump
```

To dump a database into a directory-format archive:

```
$ pg_dump -Fd mydb -f dumpdir
```

To reload an archive file into a (freshly created) database named newdb:

```
$ pg_restore -d newdb db.dump
```

From the [`pg_restore`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html) documentation:

Examples

Assume we have dumped a database called mydb into a custom-format dump file:

```
$ pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump
```

To drop the database and recreate it from the dump:

```
$ dropdb mydb
$ pg_restore -C -d postgres db.dump
```

Comment: when i do pg_restore I get 
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.

Comment: Which one I use to restore db ?

Comment: pg_restore -d newdb db.dump ?? It gives me same error

Comment: Looks like you didn't read the answer. To dump `pg_dump mydb > db.sql`, to load (in a fresh db) `psql -d newdb -f db.sql`.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: for a way to restore from a text file checkout https://serverfault.com/questions/260607/pg-dump-and-pg-restore-input-file-does-not-appear-to-be-a-valid-archive

Comment: IMO this post has a little too much detail which obfuscates the answer. What the author failed to point out is that the pg_dump documentation for the '-F' parameter does not say the default format ('p'/'plain') is suitable for pg_restore. pg_restore requires that pg_dump be used with the 'c', 'd', or 't' formats.

Comment: The answer *does* answer the question, though the comment of @Matt is right that this is not made clear enough: the answer should explain in more detail that the custom format is needed, as the [2019 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59307721/11154841) does, but the comments and their votes are misleading. They are from those who do not know the importance of `-F` and just go on to the next answer.

Answer (score 142):

The answer above didn't work for me, this worked:

`psql db_development < postgres_db.dump`

Comment: Short and sweet. Worked for me also.

Comment: Worked fine. I would just add the -U, like psql -Umyuser db_development < postgres_db.dump

Comment: Nice, It also works for me.

Comment: My data file is a plain sql file so it prompted me to use this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 83):

In order to create a backup using `pg_dump` that is compatible with `pg_restore` you must use the `--format=custom` / `-Fc` when creating your dump.

From the docs:

> Output a custom-format archive suitable for input into pg_restore.

So your `pg_dump` command might look like:

```sh
pg_dump --file /tmp/db.dump --format=custom --host localhost --dbname my-source-database --username my-username --password
```

And your `pg_restore` command:

```sh
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner --host localhost --dbname my-destination-database /tmp/db.dump
```

Comment: This answer best addresses the actual question.

Answer (score 41):

For me when i try to restore from remote host i used

```
psql -U username -p 5432 -h 10.10.10.1 -d database < db.dump
```

worked fine. And if not remote just following command worked.

```
psql -d database < db.dump
```

Comment: This command helps me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 14):

For me, It's working like this one.

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin> psql -U postgres -p 5432  -d dummy -f C:\Users\Downloads\d2cm_test.sql
```

Answer (score 8):

**If you restore .SQL file.**
Create a new database in pgAdmin.
Go to the terminal and navigate the folder/directory where your .sql file is located. And then write the following command in terminal.

Syntax:
**supername user postgres psql newDatabasename < inputfile.sql**

Examaple:

```
sudo -u postgres psql newDb < restoreDb.sql
```

Answer (score 7):

I've got same error when tried to backup db with DBeaver. If anyone uses DBeaver interface instead of command line on Windows, make sure your selected format as **tar** during backup and restore settings. [image]

Answer (score 5):

`psql -U <username> -d <database-name> -h <host-name> -f <backup.sql>`

Answer (score 4):

If you have a full DB dump:

```
PGPASSWORD="your_pass" psql -h "your_host" -U "your_user" -d "your_database" -f backup.sql
```

If you have schemas kept separately, however, that won't work. Then you'll need to disable triggers for data insertion, akin to `pg_restore --disable-triggers`. You can then use this:

```
cat database_data_only.gzip | gunzip | PGPASSWORD="your_pass" psql -h "your_host" -U root "your_database" -c 'SET session_replication_role = replica;' -f /dev/stdin
```

On a side note, it is a very unfortunate downside of postgres, I think. The default way of creating a dump in `pg_dump` is incompatible with `pg_restore`. With some additional keys, however, it is. WTF?

Answer (score 3):

Providing a simple one line answer which worked for me and will work for you too for most cases

> psql -U username -d database_name < dump_file.sql

If above gives role related errors then replace username with postgres.

> psql -U postgres -d database_name < dump_file.sql

Answer (score 2):

if you use pg_dump with -Fp to backup in plain text format, use following command:

```
cat db.txt | psql dbname
```

to copy all data to your database with name dbname

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `pg_restore` is not the right command if you have a text dump.

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with this as well. This is the combination of dump & restore commands that worked for me:

```
pg_dump -Ft -C -h database_host -U username database > DATA.dump
```

To restore

```
pg_restore -x --no-owner -d database DATA.dump
```

Remove the **-x** flag if you want to keep the **same** access privileges (ACLs) in your DB. You must have the same roles and users in the database for this.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-pgdump.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/app-pgrestore.html

Answer (score 1):

**The error is Caused due to the sql is dumped without using `-Fc` format arguments.**

The dump can be taken from -

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -Fc database_name > ~/psql/database_name.dump
```

the same can now be restored as with pg_restore-

```
pg_restore -h localhost -U postgres -d database_name ~/psql/database_name.dump
```

Reason :-

1. The Default dump from `pg_dump` can only be read using `psql` command restore.
   Like -

   psql -h localhost -U postgres database_name < database_name.dump
2. It is compulsory to provide `-Fc` in `pg_dump`, if you consider to restore from `pg_restore`

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you create a backup you want to restore it in another network or create a remote restoration.

We need to create a backup file using the `--format=custom` [`-Fc`] to restore it using `pg_restore`. We can use a connection string `postgresql://<user>:<pass>@localhost:5432/<dbname>` and replace `<user>`, `<pass>`, and `<dbname>` with your information.

```hs
pg_dump -v -Fc \
postgresql://<user>:<pass>@localhost:5432/<dbname> \
> db-20211122-163508.sql
```

To restore we will call it using `--clean` [`-c`] and `--create` [`-C`] to drop the database before restoring. Replace `<user>`, `<host>`, `<port>`, and `<dbname>` with your information.

```hs
pg_restore -vcC \
-U <user> \
-h <host> \
-p <port> \
-d <dbname> \
< db-20211122-163508.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

If you backup with this way, I think this will be more easy to import database.

pg_dump -h (remote db address) -a --column-inserts -U postgres (database name) > (file name).sql

For import,

psql 
-f (file name).sql 
--host (remote db address) 
--port 5432 
--username postgres 
--password (your password)
--dbname (database you want to import)

Answer (score -2):

*here is the solution,*

**pg_restore -U username -p 5432 -h 10.10.10.1 -d database_name < dump_file**

Comment: Does this work for you? Because this is exactly the command which leads to he error mentioned in the question.