# Restoring DB into pgAdmin4 does not accept my backup file format (.sql)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have exported a copy of my local Postgres DB from **PhpPgMyAdmin** and the resulted file is a pretty normal .sql which contains both the structure and the data of the DB.

Then I have tried to import this structure and data to a remote DB connected via **PgAdmin4** but I am getting this message at the moment:

> pg_restore: error: input file appears to be a text format dump. Please
>   use psql.

I have tried to look for some file converter online to change the file format from .sql to .psql but I couldn't find any and anyway pgAdmin4 should accept .sql files which confuses me:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like PgAdmin4 uses `pg_restore` under the hood. You should use the `psql` client to restore from a plain .sql file.

Comment: this was answered here Davide I beleive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632228/input-file-appears-to-be-a-text-format-dump-please-use-psql

Comment: I am using the PgAdmin4 Browser interface for the import, not the terminal, so that other stackoverflow question does not answer my issue.
What do you mean with "psql client"?

Comment: Found the sql query tool in PgAdmin4 and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. 
Under "Tool" select "Query Tool" and import your .sql file there.

For the query to be run I had to change the "OWNER" of the DB to the new "user" of the DB where I wanted to import the data.